# Get the difference between two SELECT statements

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am trying to get the difference between 2 `select` statements.

Here is the first `select`:

**SELECT 1**

```
SELECT *
FROM h_log_material
LEFT JOIN h_log_stkpnl
ON  h_log_stkpnl.MODULE_UNIQUE_ID = h_log_material.MODULE_UNIQUE_ID 
where 
h_log_material.WO_ID='E11TMB7M05'
and h_log_material.mtrl_type='BL'
```

**Output is 4917**

**SELECT 2**

Here is second `select`:

```
SELECT *
FROM h_log_material
LEFT JOIN h_log_stkpnl
ON  h_log_stkpnl.MODULE_UNIQUE_ID = h_log_material.MODULE_UNIQUE_ID 
where 
h_log_material.WO_ID='E11TMB7M05'
and h_log_material.mtrl_type='BL'
and h_log_stkpnl.op_id like '%STOCK-IN%'
```

**Output is 4870**

I would like to get the difference  **SELECT 1 - SELECT 2**

As output I need rows which are not in select 2.

I tried this but it returns 0.

```
SELECT *
FROM h_log_material
LEFT JOIN h_log_stkpnl
ON  h_log_stkpnl.MODULE_UNIQUE_ID = h_log_material.MODULE_UNIQUE_ID 
where 
h_log_material.WO_ID='E11TMB7M05'
and h_log_material.mtrl_type='BL'
and not exists
(SELECT *
FROM h_log_material
LEFT JOIN h_log_stkpnl
ON  h_log_stkpnl.MODULE_UNIQUE_ID = h_log_material.MODULE_UNIQUE_ID 
where 
h_log_material.WO_ID='E11TMB7M05'
and h_log_material.mtrl_type='BL'
and h_log_stkpnl.op_id like '%STOCK-IN%')
```

Answer (score 3):

The 2nd `SELECT` looks like a subset of the first so you can do

```
SELECT COUNT(*) - COUNT(CASE
                          WHEN h_log_stkpnl.op_id LIKE '%STOCK-IN%' THEN 1
                        END)
FROM   h_log_material
       LEFT JOIN h_log_stkpnl
         ON h_log_stkpnl.MODULE_UNIQUE_ID = h_log_material.MODULE_UNIQUE_ID
WHERE  h_log_material.WO_ID = 'E11TMB7M05'
       AND h_log_material.mtrl_type = 'BL'
```

**Edit**

Following your clarification that you need columns not `COUNT` try this one out

```
SELECT *
FROM   h_log_material
       LEFT JOIN h_log_stkpnl
         ON h_log_stkpnl.MODULE_UNIQUE_ID = h_log_material.MODULE_UNIQUE_ID
            AND h_log_stkpnl.op_id LIKE '%STOCK-IN%'
WHERE  h_log_material.WO_ID = 'E11TMB7M05'
       AND h_log_material.mtrl_type = 'BL'
       AND h_log_material.MODULE_UNIQUE_ID IS NULL
```

Your first query is doing a `LEFT JOIN` but the `WHERE` clause on the second one converts it into an inner join effectively. So the difference between the queries should be those rows where either there is no match in `h_log_stkpnl` or the match isn't `LIKE '%STOCK-IN%'` (I think!)

Comment: @John - Why are all your example queries using `SELECT count(*)` then? In any event `and not exists (SELECT count(*) ... ` will not work as `COUNT(*)` will always return something. Even if 0. What if you try `and not exists (SELECT * ... `

Comment: Sorry I forgot removed *  from SQL. I test something.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
and h_log_stkpnl.op_id not like '%STOCK-IN%'
```

Unless there are null values (and those can be compensated for) that should be the difference.

Comment: This I try first...not useful

Comment: @John - Ah I see your second query is basically an inner join so getting the difference will be a bit more involved.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify your platform but if you're running SQL 2008 you can use EXCEPT and INTERSECT to compare the results of two queries.

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
   SELECT h_log_material.field1,h_log_material.field2
    FROM h_log_material
    LEFT JOIN h_log_stkpnl
    ON  h_log_stkpnl.MODULE_UNIQUE_ID = h_log_material.MODULE_UNIQUE_ID 
    where 
    h_log_material.WO_ID='E11TMB7M05'
    and h_log_material.mtrl_type='BL'

    minus 

    SELECT h_log_material.field1,h_log_material.field2
    FROM h_log_material
    LEFT JOIN h_log_stkpnl
    ON  h_log_stkpnl.MODULE_UNIQUE_ID = h_log_material.MODULE_UNIQUE_ID 
    where 
    h_log_material.WO_ID='E11TMB7M05'
    and h_log_material.mtrl_type='BL'
    and h_log_stkpnl.op_id like '%STOCK-IN%'
```

Comment: It doesnt work.  MySQL Database Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT count(*)
FROM

Comment: Read carefully the query again if the problem continues to wrap the second request "()"

Comment: @Nightw0rk - `MySQL` definitely does not support `minus` (or `except`)